# Return everything after specific value

Tags: sql, oracle

Working on 10g.

I tried to write a regexp that removes everything before the first dash(-).

However, I did not anticipate the complexity of the syntax.

I have this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (myVal, '[^"]+')
```

This removes all the values after the first double quotation leaving me with data like:

```
10-3/4, 5-1/2, 7-5/8
```

I assumed that changing the double quotes to a dash and putting the carat after the dash would do it, but no luck.

Comment: Can you provide the modified regex statement, the input, the output that you expected to get, and the output that you actually got? The question is a little vague as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you need to do, then you don't need to use `REGEX`, since you could just do it with other simpler functions:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(myVal,INSTR(myVal,'-'),LENGTH(myVal))
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, try this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(myValue, '\-.*$')
FROM myTable
```

But the `SUBSTR` answer from Lamak is just as effective. The third `SUBSTR` parameter defaults to the length of the string so you can leave it off:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(myValue, INSTR(myValue, '-'))
FROM myTable
```